# NodeJs. Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript

Ошибка возникает при:

```
<script>
    require('./render.js');
</script>
```

При том, что до перезагрузки Ноута вся программа отлично работала. Как я понял, он не видит папку **node_modules**, или Node вовсе. Сама NodeJs у меня установлена и работает корректно, более того, саму программу (через **.bat**) запускает отлично, и без проблем.

**Проблема не в main.js**, как на скрине ниже. **Я делал пробег через Debug** и ошибка возникает в первую очередь на **"require"**. *VSC не видит ошибок в коде.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: ```require``` нет в браузере.

Comment: Ошибка возникла 2 или 3 дня назад, это NodeJs, и я уже писал, что всё работало...

Comment: А в nodejs нет `<script>`

Comment: ошибся, electron. При создании приложения этот код (скрипт) нужно обязательно указывать в теле сайта, иначе есть вероятность, что программа не запуститься